# SPI Clock Frequency vs FPGA Internal Clock Frequency

Tags: fpga, spi

Treating the FPGA as a SPI Slave, I've read that on the FPGA it is easier to sample the SPI Clock with the internal clock as opposed to trying to cross the clock domain within the logic.

With that being said, I have a 100Mhz clock and I am trying to implement a 20Mhz SPI clock to read data.

I am having issues with higher SPI clock rates, could it possibly be my internal FPGA clock is too slow?

Which leads to my next question ... Is there a standard to how much faster the FPGA clock should be compared to the SPI clock if one were to take the approach of syncing the SPI clock with the internal FPGA clock?

Thank you

Comment: If you cannot guarantee 3, better 4 samples per bit it's better to cross clock domains instead (e.g., use a FIFO driven by SPI master clock on one side and your logic clock on the other).

Comment: What's the duty cycle of the SPI clock? If it is more than 50%, invert it (calculate 1 - duty cycle); otherwise use the duty cycle directly. Multipy the FPGA clock with that value. The value should be significantly higher than the SPI clock if you want to sample. Example: If the duty cycle is 40%, 100 MHz * 40% = 40 MHz. This is higher than 20 MHz => Good. If it is 78%, then 100 MHz * (1 - 78%) = 22 MHz. This is quite close to the 20 MHz => Not good. And 90%? 100 MHz * (1 - 90%) = 10 MHz < 20 MHz => This will not work at all...